# How can I center a fragment vertically and horizontally?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In a fragment, I have a RelativeLayout defined like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center"/>
```

For this layout, I defined the width and height sizes.

How can I make this View in my fragment centered vertically and horizontally relative to its parent? I tried setting `gravity` to `"center"` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 8):

First you have understand gravity and layout_gravity properties :

```
layout_gravity="center" : which is align View to center of parent
gravity="center" : which is align content of View to center
```

Now in your case you have use RelativeLayout as parent so layout_gravity property not applicable so use below property to align fragment to center of parent :

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

when using `RelativeLayout` as your parent, you can set `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your child and it'll become center horizontally and vertically.